# How are visits, pageviews, and bounce rate related in Alexa's stats reporting?

Tags: seo, alexa

My site has 40,000 visits with 76,000 pageviews.  If there is a bounce rate of 44%, then does it mean that only 15,000 users generated the 67,000 page views or that 50,000 visits generated the 78,000 page views.

My site's Alexa ranking is still getting worse day by day. When I started to do SEO for my site, it was at 13,000 but it is now at 23,000. I am highly disappointment about my Alexa Ranking. It's keep on increasing day by day.  I drove 10K+ traffic everyday to my website from different sources such as Search Engines, Social Media and other quality referral's.
Can any one suggest how to control that?

Comment: Alexa rank is not a big matter and it is based on Alexa tool. I wouldnt give much importance to Alexa rank

Comment: but clients are looking only alexa ranks depends upon traffic,when i started seo it increasing day by day.iam so disappointed

Comment: Perhaps you (as the professional/expert), should be educating your clients better on metrics that matter. If you can't, then you're not doing your job properly. (downvoted as there are hundreds of questions on Alexa on SE).

Answer (score 1):

Alexa ranking has nothing to do with the data you can see in Google Analytics. Alexa ranking is close to meaningless, they only generate data based on users of their browser add-ons and tools so it bears no true representation of traffic or improvement/progress.

It certainly isn't a metric that you or your clients should be benchmarking against but instead, use the data that Google Analytics is reporting in a way that will show your clients how your efforts are improving their website.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to SEO and ranking of the website, you should consider referring to the DA and PR (Domain Authority and Page Rank). If they are increasing it means there is a improvement. You should also check if the keywords you are targeting are listed in organic search. These point in my opinion should be set as benchmark at initial stage.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the question being asked. Or at least could be extended to become more relevant to the content of the original question.

Comment: As mentioned by user35767 " but clients are looking only alexa ranks depends upon traffic,when i started seo it increasing day by day.iam so disappointed –". I informed that instead of considering alexa he should refer PR and DA. It was relevant because just referring alexa is not sufficient.

Comment: a) you didn't even mention Alexa in your answer which is all the OP contained b) the OP asked how to control Alexa ranking not can you suggest alternatives because it isn't sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions about your stats:

- Visits: 40,000
- Pageviews: 76,000
- Bounce rate: 44%
- Visits with just one page view: 17,600 (44% of 40k)
- Visits with multiple page views: 22,400 (56% of 40k)
- Page views from visitors with multiple page views: 58,400 (76k-17.6k)